# Theme specific taxonomy page

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I cant seem to find a proper way to do this, I found ways for d5 but nothing on d7 so I am asking how can I edit a specific taxonomy page in d7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use template suggestion to override page.tpl.php for specific taxonomy term page. For this to work template suggestion file should be named page--taxonomy--term--[ID].tpl.php., where [ID] - ID number of taxonomy term for which you want to edit the page.

More on template suggestions: http://drupal.org/node/1089656

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, if you want to override the taxonomy term page per vocabulary you can use [Taxonomy Display](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_display) module.