# How to theme specific taxonomy term page?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Theme specific taxonomy page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16182/theme-specific-taxonomy-page)

I have a taxonomy term page that shows all the related terms with their details ... i just need to show the list of the terms as links to node page. Which is the best way to do it?

EDIT: i tried to create taxonomy-term--VOCAB.tpl.php file, it is read but $content variable is empty .... so i don't understand how Drupal handles it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to show it by [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module. You blocked default viewing of taxonomy and change it to Views. [Video](http://mustardseedmedia.com/podcast/episode31) include.